# Error when trying to retrieve BusinessPartnerUUID

Tags: java, s4sdk

I've followed this deep dive blog 12.
[Deep Dive 12](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/05/deep-dive-9-use-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-in-the-application-programming-model-for-sap-cloud-platform/)
It ran okay.
And I am more interested in BusinessPartnerUUID, so I modify the file service-model.cds.

```
using API_BUSINESS_PARTNER as bp from './external/csn/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER';

service CrudService{

 @cds.persistence.skip
 Entity BusinessPartner as projection on bp.A_BusinessPartnerType{
   BusinessPartner,
   LastName,
   FirstName,
   BusinessPartnerCategory,
   BusinessPartnerUUID
  };
}
```

However, when I run this time, the service returns

```
The type 'class java.lang.String' of the value object is not supported.
```

As I do some googling, it leads me to this method
[Method internalValueToString](https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata2/blob/master/odata2-lib/odata-core/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/odata2/core/edm/EdmGuid.java)

This is handled by the application programming model
What can I do in this case to resolving the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue. It appears that the used Olingo lib has a problem with the type conversion of the UUID field. However I am not sure yet what causes the problem.

For the moment you can do the following:

Adjust the service definition by referring to a custom Business Partner entity definition instead. This is the same approach as in Step 3. of the Deep Dive.

service.cds:

```
using my.app from '../db/data-model';

service CrudService {
 @cds.persistence.skip
 entity BusinessPartner as projection on bookshop.BusinessPartners;
}
```

data-model.cds

```
entity BusinessPartners {
 key BusinessPartner : String(10);
 LastName: String(40);
 FirstName: String(40);
 BusinessPartnerUUID: String(36);
}
```

The UUID Field is of type CDS UUID and translates to OData EDM UUID field -> String(36).

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have one more question regarding Query Business Partners. I see that the APM is using SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development and I recall that the SDK doesn't support $filter operation. What if I want to filter BusinessPartners, for example $filter=BusinessPartnerUUID eq '<value>'?

Comment: Hello, I would suggest you open a new question for that, which will make it easier for other people to find it if they face the same issue. Thanks.